# C# WinForms TabControl Remove Tab and close child controls

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a parent container (form) that initializes a new TabPage with a user control inside of it (called from the Menu Strip). The Tab Control has a Context Menu that, when you right click and select "Close Selected Tab", I call a method that Removes that tab. However, it does not stop the code within that TabPage's user control from running. How can I clean this up so when I close the Tab (TabPages.Remove... etc) that it also closes the user control within that TabPage so that any background code stops executing?

The code below is what closes the tab:
The latter part just selects the next tab to the left after the tab is removed.

```
       public static void closeCurrentTab(TabControl tc)
    {
        int curTabIndex = tc.SelectedIndex;
        TabPage tp = tc.SelectedTab;
        tc.TabPages.Remove(tp);
        if(curTabIndex > 0)
        {
            tc.SelectedTab = tc.TabPages[(curTabIndex - 1)];
        }       
    }
```

Comment: What code do you mean? What events are tab page bound to?

Comment: I have a collection of user controls used in this program, each user control loads up inside of a new TabPage within this form. When I call TabPages.Remove(TabPage I want to remove), the code fromthe user control inside this tab page continues executing.

Comment: So oncethe user control is loaded, a new Tab Page is created with the control added to it (TabPage.Controls.Add(New user control)). Removing the tab will take it off of the Tab Control, but leave teh user control running.

Comment: TabPage has a reference to the `.Dispose` property. Try calling it like `tp.Dispose()`

Comment: Unfortunately I had originally tried this and still did not get the code to stop executing. I added it back in :     int curTabIndex = tc.SelectedIndex;
            TabPage tp = tc.SelectedTab;
            tc.TabPages.Remove(tp);

            if (curTabIndex > 0)
            {
                tc.SelectedTab = tc.TabPages[(curTabIndex - 1)];
            }
            tp.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("Tab removed!");

I ran code within the user control to give me a message box every 5 seconds, which it continues to do so after disposing of the tab.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I found that the asynchronous processes within the child control were running astray even after the parent control (in this case being the TabPage) was disposed of.

A simple example of how I solved it is below.

Also, for more complex task chaining , I can introduce cancellation tolkens once the parent becomes null, thus cleaning up whatever needs to be once a user closes a tab hosting that control, but doesnt close the overall application.

using this.Parent and testing whether it is null or not whevenever id like to.

```
        protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnParentChanged(e);
        if(this.Parent == null)
        {
        // Clean up

        }
    }
```

and \ or this

```
 private async Task popUp()
    {
        do
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Im running!");
            await Task.Delay(5000);
        }
        while (this.Parent != null);
    }
```